# protractor fails to run with directConnect

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run protractor by connecting directly to Chrome, not running Selenium. As the docs say, this is possible by setting the `directConnect` to `true` in the config file.

When I run protractor with `directConnect: true`, I get:

> Using ChromeDriver directly...
>   [launcher] Running 1 instances of
>   WebDriver Error: spawn ENOENT
>       at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34) [launcher] Process exited with error code 1

If I run protractor without `directConnect` and instead specify my selenium url, everything runs fine.

I'm running Protractor version 1.6.1, Chrome version 41.0.2272.35 beta-m (64-bit), and Chromedriver version 2.13.0.

Comment: What `protractor` and `chrome` versions are you using? Thanks.

Comment: Also, please provide with a complete traceback.

Comment: Did you run `webdriver-manager update`?

Comment: @AndresD yes, webdriver-manager has been run.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** While the solution below worked for me, after talking with a protractor dev I realized that if I run `webdriver-manager update` to install a local chromedriver, then I don't need to set the  `chromeDriver` setting in my protractor config.

---

I had the same issue and solved it by varying the `chromeDriver` path setting in protractor-conf.js depending on whether I was on Windows or OSX/Linux.

Solution and writeup below assumes you are using chromedriver provided by `npm install chromedriver`. Also this solution worked with protractor `3.2.2` and chromedriver `2.21.2`.

Protractor+chromedriver worked on OSX and Linux but I was getting ENOENT errors on Windows. I have filed an issue [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3069) and have also documented a workaround.

The issue (I think) is that childProcess.spawn has issues on Windows (see a list of issues [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn)) and the `node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver` file will not correctly run when called via `childProcess.spawn` - likely because this file is not executable and Windows doesn't know to use the `node` binary to interpret the file.

The workaround is to provide the path to the windows executable when running on Windows. It is easy enough - though hackish - to vary the `chromeDriver` arg in protractor-conf.js as demonstrated below :

protractor-conf.js for all three OS:

```
var chromeDriverPath = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe' : 'node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver';

exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  chromeDriver: chromeDriverPath,
  specs: [
    'features/*.feature'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    platform: 'ANY',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--test-type']
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`ENOENT` means Error, NO such ENTity, and relates to the file system.

Check you have the right [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) set in the `chromeDriver` option.

`capabilities : {
        chromeOptions: {
            "debuggerAddress":"127.0.0.1:8088"
        }
    },
    directConnect: true,
    chromeDriver : "../bin/chromedriver_2.15.322448.exe"`